# Two directional derivative problems

Tags: multivariable-calculus

(NOT HOMEWORK)

> **Question 1**:
>   Assume that the temperature at the point (x,y,z) in space  is given by the equation
>   $$W = 50 + xyz.$$
>   You are standing at the point $P(3,4,1)$ in a mountain valley shaped like the surface 
>   $$z = x^2 - 2y.$$
>   Suppose that you start climbing with unit speed and a northeast compass heading. What initial rate of change of temperature do you observe?

I first input the $z$ equality into $W$. Then I took the directional derivative of $W$ and evaluated it at $P$. Then took the unit vector in the direction of NE in terms of $i$ and $j$. I take the dot product of the two 2D vectors to get the direction derivative. So my answer is $55/\sqrt 2$. But the answer is $\frac{55}{6}\sqrt 2$. What went wrong? Was my procedure incorrect or was there a computational mistake?

> **Question 2**:
>   Show that the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$ and the elliptical cone $z^2 = a^2x^2 + b^2y^2$ are orthogonal at every point of there intersection.

Would it suffice just to take the gradient vector of the sphere and elliptical cone at $(x,y,z)$. Then taking there dot product and equating it to zero. Rearranging the equality gives me the equation of the cone. Now I'm stuck. How would this show that they are orthogonal at their intersection?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the first you forgot that initially you are not moving horisontally. As $Dz \cdot(1,1)=6-2=4$ we get $\sqrt{18}= 3 \sqrt{2}$ (modulo possible errors in my calculations) for the length of the 3D directional vector. You should divide by that.

For the 2nd your method is fine. You end up with (const times) $a^2x^2+b^2y^2-z^2$ but this is precisely zero because you are on the cone.